# Cocos2dx c++ compilation error for Android - 'rapidjson' does not name a type

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

When compiling to android platform, I'm receiving the following error:

```
"error: 'Value' in namespace 'rapidjson' does not name a type"
```

Everything was working fine before using RapidJson.
I'm still can successfully build the project in wp8_1 platform.
I don't know if it's a bug or I'm missing something.
I'm using Cocos2dx v3.13.1.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The file was missing the following statement...

```
#include "cocos-ext.h"
```

I got confused because it works without the include in wp8 platform.